# Postgresql duplicate last row in group

Tags: postgresql

I have a set of data like this.

```sql
   detail_id          working_time       employee_id     additional_info
      10           2020-08-26 01:00:00         1              10
      10           2020-08-26 02:00:00         1              20
      10           2020-08-26 03:00:00         1              30
      10           2020-08-26 04:00:00         1              40
      10           2020-08-26 05:00:00         1              50
      10           2020-08-26 06:00:00         1              60 
      10           2020-08-26 07:00:00         1              70
      10           2020-08-26 08:00:00         2              80
      10           2020-08-26 09:00:00         2              90
      10           2020-08-26 10:00:00         2             100
      10           2020-08-26 11:00:00         2             110
      10           2020-08-26 12:00:00         2             120
      10           2020-08-26 13:00:00         2             130
      10           2020-08-26 14:00:00         2             140
      10           2020-08-26 15:00:00         2             150
      10           2020-08-26 16:00:00         1             160
      10           2020-08-26 17:00:00         1             170
      10           2020-08-26 18:00:00         1             180
```

Imagine that we have two workers who are working on the same detail in two shifts.
The first employee is working from `01:00:00 - 07:00:00`,
second is working from `07:00:00 - 15:00:00`, first again started working from `15:00:00 - 18:00:00`

So, basically I need to duplicate the last row (grouped by employee_id) in the select in case if employee_id is changing. The final result should look like

```sql
   detail_id          working_time       employee_id     additional_info
      10           2020-08-26 01:00:00         1              10
      10           2020-08-26 02:00:00         1              20
      10           2020-08-26 03:00:00         1              30
      10           2020-08-26 04:00:00         1              40
      10           2020-08-26 05:00:00         1              50
      10           2020-08-26 06:00:00         1              60 
      10           2020-08-26 07:00:00         1              70
      10           2020-08-26 07:00:00         2              70
      10           2020-08-26 08:00:00         2              80
      10           2020-08-26 09:00:00         2              90
      10           2020-08-26 10:00:00         2             100
      10           2020-08-26 11:00:00         2             110
      10           2020-08-26 12:00:00         2             120
      10           2020-08-26 13:00:00         2             130
      10           2020-08-26 14:00:00         2             140
      10           2020-08-26 15:00:00         2             150
      10           2020-08-26 15:00:00         1             150
      10           2020-08-26 16:00:00         1             160
      10           2020-08-26 17:00:00         1             170
      10           2020-08-26 18:00:00         1             180
```

I know how to find a place of changing employee_id by using `lead` function:

```sql
WHEN lag(employee_id) OVER (ORDER BY detail_id, working_time) <> employee_id THEN ...
```

but I don't know how to duplicate row

Link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1795d0/10)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `lead()` worker as you already know and compare that to the current worker. But I suspect that you rather want `PARTITION BY detail_id` instead of `ORDER BY`. Your example isn't clear enough in that respect as there is only one `detail_id`.

But a `CASE` expression is of little use here, as it cannot produce additional rows. But you can compare the `lead()` worker against the current worker in a `WHERE` clause. If they're different, the row is one of the additional rows. Use `UNION ALL` to add that to the other "plain" row from the table.

If you want to order the end result put that `UNION ALL` operation in yet another derived table and `SELECT` from that with an `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT y.detail_id,
       y.working_time,
       y.employee_id,
       y.additional_info
       FROM (SELECT w.detail_id,
                    w.working_time,
                    w.employee_id,
                    w.additional_info
                    FROM workers w
             UNION ALL
             SELECT x.detail_id,
                    x.working_time,
                    x.lead_employee_id employee_id,
                    x.additional_info
                    FROM (SELECT w.detail_id,
                                 w.working_time,
                                 w.employee_id,
                                 w.additional_info,
                                 lead(w.employee_id) OVER (PARTITION BY w.detail_id
                                                           ORDER BY w.working_time) lead_employee_id
                                 FROM workers w) x
                    WHERE x.lead_employee_id <> x.employee_id) y
       ORDER BY y.working_time;
```

What is odd though is that your rule doesn't seem to apply to the row with `2020-08-26 01:00:00`. How is that the actual start time and not the record before (which doesn't exists, I know) but for all the other cases it's not the actual time but the time before? Maybe you should rework how you store the data and just always insert the actual starting and ending time too.

And your fiddle uses MySQL instead of Postgres BTW.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I've already fixed this problem using `unnest` function.